# Android login form the values does not pass to the database

Tags: android, database, connection

I created a login form for an android application

Here's my MainActivity.java file

```
    package com.chi.tripassist;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener {

    EditText username, password;
    Button btnsub;


    String Username, Password;

    HttpClient httpclient;

    HttpPost httppost;
    ArrayList<NameValuePair>nameValuePairs;
     HttpResponse response;
     HttpEntity entity;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        username=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
        password=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        btnsub=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnsub);

        btnsub.setOnClickListener(this);



    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {


        HttpParams httpParameter = new BasicHttpParams();

        httpclient=new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameter);

        httppost=new HttpPost("http://192.168.43.2/mydb/connection.php");


        Username=username.getText().toString();
        Password=password.getText().toString();




        try
        {

            nameValuePairs=new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username",Username));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password",Password));


            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            response=httpclient.execute(httppost);

            if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()==200)
            {
                entity=response.getEntity();

                if(entity != null)
                {
                    InputStream instream=entity.getContent();

                    JSONObject jsonresponse=new JSONObject(convertStreamToString(instream));

                    String username=jsonresponse.getString("username");
                    String password=jsonresponse.getString("password");


                    if(username.equals(username) && password.equals(password))
                    {

                        SharedPreferences sp=getSharedPreferences("logindetails", 0);

                        SharedPreferences.Editor spedit=sp.edit();

                        spedit.putString("username", username);
                        spedit.putString("password", password);


                        spedit.commit();

                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SUCCESS!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();




                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Invalid username & password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    }
            }

        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Connection error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    private static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
        try {
        is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
        return sb.toString();
        }


}
```

Here's my activity_main.xml file

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.chi.tripassist.MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/title" />

    <EditText 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/hntuser"
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:inputType="text"/>


    <EditText 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/hntpwd"
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"/>

    <Button 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btnsub"
        android:text="@string/login"/>


    <Button 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btnreg"
        android:text="@string/signup"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And here's my manifest file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.chi.tripassist"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

connection.php file

```
<?php
   $dbhost="localhost";
   $dbuser="root";
   $dbpwd="";
   $db="mydb";


   $con=mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpwd,$db)or die("connnection error");
    mysql_select_db($db)or die("database selection error");


   $username=$_POST['username'];
   $password=$_POST['password'];

   $sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'");

   $num=mysql_num_rows($sql);

   if($num==1)
   {
   while($list=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
   {
   $output=$list;

   echo json_encode($output);

    mysql_close();
    }
    }
    ?>


I ran the app on my phone and gave the ip address which was on the wifi hotspot
```

It gives the toast "Connection error!" which is in the catch part of the try catch block.

the username and password are the two fields in the users table.

I created a small html page and test the php file and it gave the jason output. But I cant login.

Comment: Have you checked that you can connect to the database manually as in by entering the localcost/connection.php address into your browser. If it returns the same error your values in making the connection to the database are incorrect.Also ensure your wamp server is ONLINE

Comment: Can you paste the stack trace here?

Comment: Thanks Neo yes I tried to connect to the database using a html file and it gave correct response with the jason array.

Comment: Investigate the stack trace that you see in the Logcat window or post it here if you can. That will give clues as to why you get the Exception.